# Deep copy of a graph in python

Tags: python, graph

How can I make a deep copy of a directed graph in Python? Are there any existing modules in python to deal with graph structures? Each node has a `data` field and a `neighbors` field, which is a `list` storing references to neighboring nodes.

Comment: How is your graph represented right now? I mean in terms of Python objects. Lists, tuples, etc. We cannot tell you how to copy something unless you show us what the original object is.

Comment: There are plenty of python libs that deal with graphs such as networkx, igraph etc.. all of them understand graph structure, attributes and such and support deep copying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx

G1 = nx.Graph()
G1.add_edge(1, 2)
G2 = G1.copy()   # makes a deep copy of G1 into G2
G2.add_edge(1, 3)    

print G1.nodes()    # prints [1, 2]
print G2.nodes()    # prints  [1, 2, 3]
```

You can find more here: https://networkx.github.io/

Comment: Actually that returns a shallow copy.  Use G2 = G1.copy() for a deep copy.